# JBoss EAP 7.1 installer for RHEL 7

Tags: installation, jboss-eap-7

We are currently trying to setup the JBoss EAP 7.1 on RHEL 7, but have some question on which installer that we should use.

The scenario is, we are currently setting up the production environment to be used as a user testing environment, upon which passed successfully, will be promoted as a production environment. Client prefers to purchase the JBoss and thus activate the JBoss subscription license only when the test is passed.

As such, we would only be able to install using the Developer edition. My question is, if we use that to install in the server, once we get the actual subscription license, do we need to reinstall the app server?

What is the difference between the developer edition and the full subscription edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same product!
There is a no need to re-install or update the previous installation.
The subscription lcense has to do with the support of the product.

Comment: In the following URL you can find the Subscription Guide for Red Hat JBoss Middleware for detailed information: https://www.redhat.com/en/resources/subscription-guide-red-hat-jboss-middleware